# Synchronize preferences between macs?

Tags: data-synchronization, preferences

I use four different Macs on a daily basis. I would love to be able to synchronize preferences between them. This is an obvious feature that is missing from iCloud. I'm thinking of writing software to explicitly synchronize `$HOME/Library/Preferences`. However, apps won't be expecting that, so there is going to be some need to exclude some apps. Other apps would probably benefit from having elements within the plist merged. Has anybody done this?

Comment: Proceed with caution. The data in that folder contains window size and positioning; file paths of recent documents; and other parameters that might be machine specific, or even status-specific.

Comment: Also, apps that are sandboxed may have their preferences inside ~/Library/Containers/$APPNAME/Data/Library/Preferences

Comment: So do I need to write a sync app?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you need to decide which particular data you want to sync, rather than just syncing the entire folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t work well in practice due to the flexibility and creativity in how applications save preferences. Some applications even generate machine specific settings tied to each device as a feature which will defeat any sync you set up or revert to defaults when you restore from a full backup.

This was one reason why I switched to embracing the defaults and made far fewer tweaks when I would regularly use dozens of machines sequentially for work.

Short of making your home folder network shareable across all computers, there isn’t a good method for this general problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many macOS system preferences will happily synch via iCloud. It works on my two machines (Big Sur and Catalina).

Go to System Preferences > AppleID > iCloud Drive > Options, then scroll down to the end of the list, and check the box next to "System Preferences."

Comment: Oddly, I do not have that option on my macOS Monterey 12.1. And I have "Desktop & Documents Folders" listed twice. And this is a new machine! But I do have it on macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.3.

Comment: I guess the problem with this approach, also, is that each application needs to manually adopt it, which doesn't help me for the vast majority of my applications

Comment: I too don’t have settings in iCloud Drive either as a sync enabled application. Also, why Maps is the last listed and there’s no sort by name or size in that UI…